# Regex Find and Replace in String

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a few strings that look like the following:

```
xml=<data><optional><Account>192</Account></optional></data>, submitter=Q102, target=Q10, escalationType=esc, escalationReason=277, feedback=cx req live esc to have us review, adv cx his account is pending, preventable=0,
```

What I am trying to do is write a regular expression in excel (vb) to find all the text between `feedback=` and `, preventable` and replace all `,` in that with a PIPE instead.

This is the expression I have so far to find that text:

```
(?<=feedback=)(.*)(?=, preventable)/gi
```

However, I'm not too sure what to do at this point to replace text within that selection?

Here is the expected string after it has ran:

```
 xml=<data><optional><Account>192</Account></optional></data>, submitter=Q102, target=Q10, escalationType=esc, escalationReason=277, feedback=cx req live esc to have us review| adv cx his account is pending, preventable=0,
```

Here is a link to the Regex I am working with in my test: https://regex101.com/r/wR1dL0/2

Comment: If there will always have two phrases, then it could help: _https://regex101.com/r/wR1dL0/3_

Comment: Sadly it could be a paragraph long with commas in any part of it so I'm not sure if its even possible with one epression

Comment: You probably want to use non-greedy `.+?` there. But, normally when you want to do two separate things in a single replace function, you would use a _callback_ functionality. For example, in the replacement portion, specify a function that returns a replacement. In that function, take all from capture group 1, replace `, -> |`, then return the result.

Comment: A problem with your regex:  VBScript Regular Expressions does not support look behind or mode modifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At regex101 you have selected the PCRE flavor, but if you want to use VBA, you need to select the javascript flavor.  In particular, look-behinds are not valid; nor are mode modifiers, in vbscript (javascript).

A regex that will match as you require would be:

```
,(?!.*feedback)(?=.*,\s*preventable)
```

The replacement string would merely be the PIPE

A UDF implementing that in VBA might be:

---

```
Option Explicit
Function CommaToPipeBetween(S As String, StartAt As String, EndAt As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim sPat As String

sPat = ",(?!.*" & StartAt & ")(?=.*,\s*" & EndAt & ")"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    .ignorecase = True

    CommaToPipeBetween = .Replace(S, "|")

End With

End Function
```

---

The UDF assumes that you do not want to replace a comma just before `EndAt` if it is separated by 0 or more `space` characters.  But you could change the pattern to make things more generalized, if you want.